# php no guarda los datos en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy en mi primer código donde aprendo a cargar datos de php a mysql. Hice un formulario sencillo para cargar datos dni y nombre. Quisiera saber porque puede ser que no me guarde los datos en la BD. No me salta ningún error.. solo cuando quiero cerrar la conexión que me aparece el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_close(): Argument #1 ($mysql) must be of type mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ABM\agregar.php:59 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ABM\agregar.php(59): mysqli_close('') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ABM\agregar.php on line 59

El código es el siguiente, esta todo en el mismo archivo para no mezclarme por ahora:

```
<?php
    $sql = '';
    $resultado = '';
    $conexion  = '';
    if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
        $dni  = $_POST['dni'];
        $nombre  = $_POST['nombre'];

        //conexion
        $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bdp");
        if ($conexion) {
            echo"Error en la conexion";
        }
        echo mysqli_connect_error();
        echo mysqli_error($conection); 
        die();

        //consulta
        $sql= "INSERT INTO admin VALUES ('$dni','$nombre')";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
        
        //control
        if($resultado){
                printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($conexion));
            //echo"Hubo Algun Error";
            }else{
            echo"Datos Guardados Correctamente";
            }
        if($resultado){
            echo "<script> lenguaje='JavaScript'> alert('correcto');       
            </script>";
            
            }else{
            echo "<script> lenguaje='JavaScript'> alert('incorrecto');
            </script>";
        if($conexion){
            echo "<script> lenguaje='JavaScript'> alert('conexion correcto');       
            </script>";
            }else{
            echo "<script> lenguaje='JavaScript'> alert('conexion incorrecto');
            </script>";
            }
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Desde ya muchas gracias!!!

Comment: ¿Que se supone que significa esto: **`if ($conexion) { echo"Error en la conexion"; }`**?

Comment: @A.Cedano creo que quiso hacer un "debugger" pero "cambió" los resultados de las salidas. Más adelante hace un `die();` creo que por ahí podría ir el problema.

Comment: @OCHOA, OP afirma esto: *"Quisiera saber porque puede ser que no me guarde los datos en la BD. No me salta ningun error"* Con ese código, si no salta el mensaje `Error en la conexion` es porque hay error en la misma, dado que ese `if` es contradictorio. Lo que expresa es: *Si la conexión es correcta, imprime que hay un error en ella*. No sé si me explico.

Comment: Luego, aquí `echo mysqli_error($conection);` usa una variable `$conection` que no es definida en ninguna parte.

Comment: Eso le dije. Cambió el resultado de la "comprobación" de la conexión. El `if` no funciona así. Además luego, fuera de condicionales hace un `die();`

Comment: Tampoco entiendo que significa `lenguaje`, en la parte de los scripts por ejemplo este `<script> lenguaje='JavaScript'> alert('correcto');       
            </script>` y los demás.

Comment: @A.Cedano es un claro error de escritura. Supongo que quiso poner **languaje**.

Comment: @OCHOA la forma correcta sería: `<script language="javascript">`, o sea, dentro del tag `script`, definir el lenguaje. Dicho eso, yo creo que OP está aprendiendo de una fuente pre-histórica, pues `language="javascript"` se usaba en HTML anterior a 4, y ¡ya estamos en HTML 5!. Desde HTML 4 el estándar es `<script type="text/javascript">`. Otro apunte con respecto a tu respuesta: deberías poner todo el código funcional dentro del `try`, no solamente la conexión. Quizá yo vengo de lenguajes menos permisivos que PHP y esto no dé problemas, pero PHP está corrigiendo muchas prácticas permisivas.

Comment: @A.Cedano como siempre tiene razón en lo del `try`, pero no quiero "ofuscar" tanto al OP. Poco a poco podemos subir el nivel, por el momento considero, a mi criterio, que si el OP entiende mis códigos (básicos), puede aprender y retener mejor.

Comment: @OCHOA Es que ya metiste a OP *para lo hondo*, como se suele decir en mi tierra, al usar manejo de excepciones en tu código :). Así que ya que estamos, es mejor meter todo lo relativo a la conexión dentro del `try`, creo que así es menos confuso y se aprende desde el principio a implementar buenas prácticas.

Answer (score 0):

Te daré un pequeño script que te ayudara a mejorar y aprender un poco (eso espero).

Este script emula muy bien lo que tu tienes. Pruébalo y me comentas.

```
<?php
    /* check the conn */
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    try {
        // database connection data
        $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','','pruebas');
    }
    catch( Exception $e ) {
        echo "Error al Conectar. Error N°: " . $e->getCode() . " | " . $e->getMessage();
        return;
    }

    // get the post records
    $txtNombre = $_POST['txtNombre'];
    $txtDni = $_POST['txtDni'];
    $nombreCompleto = $_POST['nombreCompleto'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $check = $_POST['check'];

    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_POST);
    echo "</pre>";

    // database insert SQL code
    $sql = "INSERT INTO db_privacidad (id, nombre, dni, nombreCompleto, fecha, aceptacion) VALUES ('0', '$txtNombre', '$txtDni', '$nombreCompleto', '$fecha', '$check')";

    // insert in database
    $rs = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    if($rs) {
        echo "Formulario enviado con éxito.";
    }
```

En mi caso, me gusta darles mi toque personal, y cuando hago un código puro tengo este script que funciona muy bien.

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'pruebas');

class DBM{

    // Para llamar al metodo privado conectar()
    public function conexion()
    {
        return self::conectar();
    }
    // Metodo privado donde hacemos la conexion a la DB
    private function conectar(){
        $MySQLi = $this->mysqli = new MySQLi (DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_DATABASE);

        if ($MySQLi->connect_errno){
            $debugger = '<b>Error al conectar al Servidor !!!<br>Error '.$MySQLi->connect_errno.':</b> '.$MySQLi->connect_error;
            echo $debugger;
            $error ='<br>
                    <div class="centrar" style="font-size:25px;">
                        <div class="label label-danger">
                            Error de Conexion, contacte con un Administrador !!!
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>';
            echo $error;
        }
        else{
            // Definimos el charset de la DataBase
            $MySQLi->set_charset('utf8');

            // DataBase connection info
            // var_dump($this->mysqli);

            $response = '';
            $response .= $this->mysqli->host_info . "<br>";
            $response .= 'Conectado al Servidor: <b>'.DB_HOST.'</b><br>';
            $response .= 'Base de Datos: <b>'.DB_DATABASE.'</b><br>';

            $response .= ('Conjunto de caracteres de la Base de Datos es: <b>'.$this->mysqli->character_set_name().'</b><br>');
            echo $response;
        }
    }

    // Metodo publico para desconectarnos
    public function desconectar(){
        $MySQLi = $this->mysqli;

        // Si hay una conexion, la cerramos
        if (isset($MySQLi)) {
            $cerrar = $MySQLi->close();
            // Destruimos la variable
            unset($MySQLi);
            if ($cerrar) {
                $response = '<hr>Conexion a la Base de Datos Cerrada !!!';
            }
            else{
                $response = '<hr>La Conexion a la Base de Datos sigue Abierta !!!';
            }
        }
        else{
            $response = '<hr>Conexion no esta definida';
        }
        echo $response;
    }
}

$dbm = new DBM();
$dbm->conexion();
$dbm->desconectar();
```

El resultado es el siguiente

[image: Conexión MySQL]

Comment: si es una clase puedes utilizar el metodo: `function __destruct() {}` que hari lo mismo que el metodo `desconectar()` pero este se ejecutara de manera automatica.

Comment: @Bryro, para ser honesto sigo optando por una función `desconectar`, más que por un destructor. [acá hay una pregunta sobre eso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67641789/is-destruct-in-php-needed) y la verdad es que me parece "mejor" mi método. Es como gustos digámoslo así.